# DNSclient is not picking up hostname from DNSserver but it is able to ping it

Tags: linux

I Have Window 7 as Host Machine and I have installed Redhat 5.3 and Centos 5.4 as Vmware Machines under Window 7 through Vmware Workestation.I configure DNS & DHCP in Redhat 5.3(10.0.0.1) and able to do nslookup & DIG in this.I am able to ping window 7,redhat,centos with each other.

I have made one entry client30.example.com for ip 10.0.0.30 in forword and backword lookup file in DNS server(10.0.0.1).

Problem  :-

**Centos whom i have made dhcp client of Redhat(10.0.0.1) is able to get ip from dhcp server and it gets ip 10.0.0.30 (as i wanted no problem till now)
But Centos is not picking up hostanme client30.example.com as i have bind entry of ip 10.0.0.30 with client30.example.com.
Still it is picking up hostname localhost.localdomain. I check /etc/resolve.conf file of centos and i found that by default it picks nameserver 192.168.1.1(even i have not provided this ip anywhere).Everytime i made manual change in this ip again it pics same ip on reboot.**

Kindly help how i can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because VMware Workstation is itself DHCP. Please disable DHCP in VMware Workstation, You can't run two DHCP in single network subnet.

Also check /etc/sysconfig/network file, Hostname coming from there.

Comment: I have connected BOth Virtual Machine(Redhat & Centos) in VMNet8(NAT) with Window HOst.I have already disabled DHCP in Vmware(From Network Editor) but stil facing same problem..Still i am not getting why client is not picking name(client30) from nameserver(10.0.0.1) althought it is picking up ip form dhcpserver..I checked Network file of nameserver(10.0.0.1) and it have HOSTNAME=server.example.com.I also check this file of my client(10.0.0.30) & it have hostname=Localhost.localdimain..I dont want to moditfy this hostname manully as i want that this hostname my client should pick from namserver

Comment: **I think sir u misunderstood my questn.Client(10.0.0.30) is able to get IP from dhcpserver(10.0.0.1) but it is not picking up name (root@client30) from nameserver.I have mapped name client30.example.com with IP 10.0.0.30**

Comment: Also try get-lease-hostnames yes  option in DHCP. Generally when you reboot client it should pick hostname from DHCP.